# What is Bootstrap dll in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know everything about bootstrap dlls in .net, how to create them, why to create them , how could they be useful etc.

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: little more context would help

Comment: In my application, i want to load some things or want to run some piece of code before any thing else for my dll. This is suggested to achieve through bootstrapping only. But i've absolutely no idea about that, any beginners link for bootstrapping would be helpful.  Plese note i dont need this thing for creating some installation packages.

Comment: @MSingh please rephrase the question so it will more clearly state what is expected.

Answer (score 4):

I see from your comment that you are not creating MSI installer, so in general you need some custom code to run when an assembly is loaded.
For that you can use [AppDomain.AssemblyLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload.aspx) event.

```
class AssemblyLoadTest {

   public static void Main() 
   {
      // subscribe to event
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new                                
            AssemblyLoadEventHandler(MyAssemblyLoadEventHandler);

      // continue working

   }

   // will fire once an assembly is loaded
   static void MyAssemblyLoadEventHandler(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args) 
   {
       // your custom code here
       // you can check loaded assembly from args.LoadedAssembly.FullName
       ....
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what i need, but the issue is I don't have the reference of that dll right in my startup project, but refer it from some other dll, something like this  MainUI has the reference of BLL  and further BLL has the refernece of DAL, i want to write startup code for DAL, so i need some appdomain_load event for my BLL. Thanks

Comment: @MSingh I see no problem, at least you can identify once your assembly is loaded in the certain AppDomain in which you have subscribed for the event and once event occurred you can notify other interested parties.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your architecture:

1. You can have separate Starter.exe which first runs bootstrup stuff and after loads your app. ( it's better cause one time bootstrup stuff finished it will tree memeory as it makes part of other process which will be killed by OS)
2. You can try to subscribe to AssemblyLoad even of your dll's AppDomain and try to do there what you want.

Comment: Tigran jan, If I understand the question right, separate process will be a little tricky as he needs "init" code to run when dll is loaded and not when the particular application is started. Application start does not yet mean that assembly is loaded in AppDomain for that application, so most probably the better is to use AssemblyLoad event.